ST_GeneratePoints returns NULL
I have a table where it's column "geometry" contains just the value of "coordinates" (https://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=1543125).
It'll look like this on a map:

I'm trying to get a random point (latitude/longitude) that is within of one of these areas, so I wrote a query like this:
SELECT 
    ST_Area(geometry) AS area_size, 
    ST_GeometryType(geometry) AS geom_type,
    ST_IsEmpty(geometry) AS is_empty,
    ST_IsValid(geometry) AS is_valid,
    ST_GeneratePoints(geometry, 1, 1211647988) as points
from "city_data"

The problem is, it couldn't find any points (I only need 1). The result of the above query is:



area_size
geom_type
is_empty
is_valid
points




3.948334505231269
ST_MultiPolygon
false
true
NULL



But why exactly is points NULL? When I set it to st_generatepoints(geometry, 2, 1211647988), it'll return 1 point instead of 2 as you can see:

Thanks for helping me out.

What happens if you use a different seed value?

@TimothyDalton The same. I use random seeds, but it‘s always NULL.

What happens if you use just one polygon of this set? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html

Here ST_GeneratePoints on a multipolygon is kind of buggy. It returns the wrong number of points (less, same or more) and the chosen geometry points are not always random (it seems to depend on the number of parts and the number of points to be generated). As a workaround, try getting a random part then generate a random point on this simple polygon.

@JGH Tried it getting a random polygon. But if so, It'll include "holes" which aren't part of the covered area.

@TimothyDalton I don't exactly know what you mean, but I tried a lot of different cities and it's still the same everywhere.
